# How to fix Action Text in Rails 6 where rich_text_area is empty on the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

Guys I am trying to use Action Text with the rich_text_area tag. But on the page view the description field is Empty.

Here the  package.json:

```
{
      ...
        "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.3-1",
        ...
      },
      }
}
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
      ...
    actionpack (6.0.3.1)
     ...
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.3.1)
```

Yarn.lock:

```
"@rails/actiontext@^6.0.3-1":
  version "6.0.3-1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@rails/actiontext/-/actiontext-6.0.3-1.tgz#3ad0072774a243c26a21637d0cdb29ca3b5f49b5"
  integrity sha512-niwfhqefg9AwQhIg1L2mqGNAYB7z1MVSZL6yMKmJFv9/sH3HXTxrnVzBHFdOIak3/XFk3bRVZN5kRMZWyOOwzg==
  dependencies:
    "@rails/activestorage" "^6.0.0-alpha"
```

_step3.html.erb:

```
<div class="step-content <%= 'is-active' if @step == 3 %>">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="" class="label">Description</label>
        <%= f.rich_text_area :description, rows: 50, cols: 50 %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the class model:

```
class Gig < ApplicationRecord
 ...
  has_many_attached :photos
  has_rich_text :description

  ...
end
```

Description is empty:
[image]

Should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's working after re installation with command and the manual [action text installation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#installation) :

```
bin/rails action_text:install
```